# Azure Blob Storage throws exception when creating a new container. Claims it already exists, but it does not

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a blob container in Azure storage using the sample code below.

```
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var fileName = "quickstart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";

        //Create a unique name for the container
        string containerName = "quickstartblobs" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName); //Exception occurs here. 
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

        var result = blobClient.Upload(ms);
```

Despite making a new container name that clearly doesn't exist, the call to CreateBlobContainer() always creates the container in Azure and then throws an exception saying it already exists.

> 'The specified container already exists.

I verify in my Azure environment that no containers exist prior to running this code. While searching for a resolution to this problem, I have seen references to a CreateIfNotExists() method, however I don't see that method available on BlobServiceClient.

Can someone explain why this is not working as expected and what to do about it?

Comment: can you try to create an BlobContainerClient instead? On that one you can then call CreateIfNotExist() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var fileName = "quickstart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";

        //Create a unique name for the container
        string containerName = "quickstartblobs" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        containerClient.CreateIfNotExists(); 
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

        var result = blobClient.Upload(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

use overload method bloabClient.Upload(string path,bool overwite)

```
bloabClient.Upload(ms,true);
```

this may help, thanks

Ex:

```
BlobContainerClient container = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync("employeeblob");
        BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient("emp.xlsx");
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileName,true);
```

ex:
[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8MCr.png)